# Flask CLI shows "TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException"

Tags: python, flask

When I run Flask from the terminal with `flask run`, if my code has an error I see "TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException" instead of the actual error. To debug it I need to open the browser and inspect the `exc_info` variable in the Werkzeug debugger, which is not convenient. Why is Flask doing this? How can I see the actual error in the terminal?

```py
$ FLASK_APP=example flask run

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 356, in __call__
    self._flush_bg_loading_exception()
  File "[...]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 344, in _flush_bg_loading_exception
    raise exc_info
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/4096) introduced in Flask 2.0 that will be [fixed](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/4169) when Flask 2.0.2 is released. The CLI was incorrectly re-raising `sys.exc_info()` instead of only the exception object. Until then, you can turn off lazy loading by running with `flask run --eager-loading`.