# Exception TypeError TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I suspect this has something to do with the request.args['q'] in app.py because it has been causing me some other issues and I can't get it to work. Could be totally wrong though, thanks for any responses!

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, session, g, request, jsonify, json
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
import requests
from werkzeug.exceptions import Unauthorized
import os
from other import zip_code, exists, location, temp, weath

from models import connect_db, db, User, Location

CURR_USER_KEY = "curr_user"

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = (
    os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', 'postgresql:///capstone-i'))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', "weatherly53102")
app.config['DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS'] = False
API_key = '384549281a1b886956dff00758e198a3'

toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)

connect_db(app)

db.create_all()


@app.before_request
def add_user_to_g():
    """If we're logged in, add curr user to Flask global."""

    if CURR_USER_KEY in session:
        g.user = User.query.get(session[CURR_USER_KEY])

    else:
        g.user = None


def do_login(user):
    """Log in user."""

    session[CURR_USER_KEY] = user.id


def do_logout():
    """Logout user."""

    if CURR_USER_KEY in session:
        del session[CURR_USER_KEY]


@app.route('/')
def home():
    top_locs = Location.query.order_by(
        Location.times_searched.desc()).limit(10).all()
    return render_template('home.html', top_locs=top_locs)


@app.route('/location')
def get_weather():
    zip_code = request.args['q']

    response = requests.get(
        f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip={zip_code},us&appid=384549281a1b886956dff00758e198a3&units=imperial')
    weather_info = response.json()
    temp = weather_info['main']['temp']
    weath = weather_info['weather'][0]['main']
    location = weather_info['name']
    exists = Location.query.filter_by(zip_code=zip_code).first()
    if not exists:
        new_loc = Location(name=location, zip_code=zip_code)
        db.session.add(new_loc)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(f'/location/{new_loc.id}')
    else:
        ex_loc = Location.query.filter_by(name=location).first()
        return redirect(f'/location/{ex_loc.id}')


@app.route('/location/<int:loc_id>')
def display_loc(loc_id):
    zip_code = request.args['q']

    response = requests.get(
        f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip={zip_code},us&appid=384549281a1b886956dff00758e198a3&units=imperial')
    weather_info = response.json()
    temp = weather_info['main']['temp']
    weath = weather_info['weather'][0]['main']
    location = weather_info['name']
    exists = Location.query.filter_by(zip_code=zip_code).first()
    existing_loc = Location.query.get_or_404(loc_id)
    return render_template('location.html', existing_loc=existing_loc, temp=temp, weath=weath)
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% block title %}<title>Weatherly</title>{% endblock %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="/static/images/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
                <span>Weatherly</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            {% if request.endpoint != None %}
            <li>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="POST" action="/location">
                    <input name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search with zip code" id="search">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if not g.user %}
            <li><a href="/signup">Sign up</a></li>
            <li><a href="/login">Log in</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li>
                <a href="/users/{{ g.user.id }}">
                    <img src="{{ g.user.image_url }}" alt="{{ g.user.username }}">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/messages/new">New Message</a></li>
            <li><a href="/logout">Log out</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**location.html**

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% block title %}<title>Weatherly</title>{% endblock %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="/static/images/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
                <span>Weatherly</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            {% if request.endpoint != None %}
            <li>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="POST" action="/location">
                    <input name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search with zip code" id="search">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if not g.user %}
            <li><a href="/signup">Sign up</a></li>
            <li><a href="/login">Log in</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li>
                <a href="/users/{{ g.user.id }}">
                    <img src="{{ g.user.image_url }}" alt="{{ g.user.username }}">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/messages/new">New Message</a></li>
            <li><a href="/logout">Log out</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**Exception**
TypeError
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\Carter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 354, in **call**

```
def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    __traceback_hide__ = True  # noqa: F841
    if self._app is not None:
        return self._app(environ, start_response)
    self._flush_bg_loading_exception()
    with self._lock:
        if self._app is not None:
            rv = self._app
        else:
            rv = self._load_unlocked()
```

File "C:\Users\Carter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 342, in _flush_bg_loading_exception
def _flush_bg_loading_exception(self):
**traceback_hide** = True  # noqa: F841
exc_info = self._bg_loading_exc_info
if exc_info is not None:
self._bg_loading_exc_info = None
raise exc_info

```
def _load_unlocked(self):
    __traceback_hide__ = True  # noqa: F841
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
    self._bg_loading_exc_info = None
```

TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException

Comment: Please update the question to include the _entire_ error traceback message.

Comment: Did so, thank you for my patience this is my first post!

Comment: This is a bug in Flask. Please see the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710169/flask-cli-shows-typeerror-exceptions-must-derive-from-baseexception

Comment: It looks like when your app raises an exception, there is a [bug in Flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/4096) that overwrites it with the TypeError that you see here. The bug is fixed in Flask 2.0.2, which unfortunately is not yet released.

Comment: I suppose the next step would be to figure out what in your code is causing the exception to be raised, and fix that. (That's hard without a good stack trace though.)

Comment: So if i run with eager loading, will i get the correct stack trace?